# Finding errors in frequency from a Fast Fourier Transform from Gaussian fitting

Tags: algorithms, fourier-analysis

I took a FFT of sound in a box generated by a frequency sweep over a range of frequencies, and have an array of frequencies and their corresponding FFT amplitudes.  According to models for the acoustic waves, certain frequencies should be resonant frequencies, which certainly shows in the data as Gaussian-like peaks.

I was wondering if there might be some program or algorithm that can quickly determine the peaks in the spectrum as well as their standard deviations (if assumed to be Gaussian).

I already have a brute force way of doing, that is to check each point and their values on Igor Pro, and finding the value of $f$ such that the spectrum amplitude, $A = A_0 e^{-1/2}$ where $A_0$ is the peak.

This is due to the fact that the equation of the Gaussian is
$$
A_0 e^{-\frac{f^2}{2\sigma_f}}
$$
where $\sigma_f$ is the standard deviation in $f$, so that at $f=\sigma_f$, the exponential is $e^{-1/2}$.

I was wondering if there was a way to automate this.  Finding the peaks themselves would probably involve some sort of discrete derivative to find the extrema (which would have to ignore turning points due to noise fluctuations).  Then perhaps I could compare values over a range about the peaks, but of course the comparisons won't be exact equality, but instead finding the closest values, since I am working with discrete data.

Comment: Do you know beforehand how many resonances you have?